# How can I access a program´s docstrings from the command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, module, python-import

I have a python "hangman" program that lets you play hangman in the console. The functions in that program have docstrings that document what they do. I want to run a command line instruction to access those docstrings. Something like:

```
python help(hangman.py)
```

and getting something like

```
my_function()
    Counts how many rings lebron lost
...
```

I don´t know how I can get the hangman.py file to work as a module (it does not let me import it to other programs either).
If anyone knows how I can achieve these things, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share how the code if organized ? You may iterate over the method ahd display each doc

Comment: Try `pydoc hangman.my_function` or `pydoc3 hangman.my_function`. pydoc is frequently part of the python distro.

Comment: `hangman.py` is a module if its in the same directory as the top level script that imports it (or if the python shell has that current working directory). You can also add its directory to `PYTHONPATH`. But in the end, you'll want to know how to install modules. https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html#distributing-python-modules